# Send certificate in http request header - c++

Tags: authentication, certificate, client-server, x509certificate, cpprest-sdk

I have a certificate that I need to send in the header of an http request. This is how I acquired the cert:

```
    PCCERT_CONTEXT cert = nullptr;
    wstring store = // store name
    wstring subjectName = // subject name

    HCERTSTORE hStoreHandle = CertOpenStore(
        CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        0,
        NULL,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
        store.c_str());

    cert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hStoreHandle,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
        subjectName.c_str(),
        NULL);
```

I need to send it as a custom header, as the load balancer that sits in front of my service strips off the certificate header ["X-ARR-CLIENTCERT"] before forwarding the request. I believe I need to send the cert->pbCertEncoded, but on the server, I can't decode it and convert it back to an X509Certificate2.

This is what I tried on the client:

```
request.headers().add("client-cert", cert->pbCertEncoded);
```

On the server:

```
var headerCert = Request.Headers["client-cert"];
byte[] certdata = Convert.FromBase64String(headerCert);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certdata);
```

The request header on the server is non-null. But it cannot parse it back to an X509Certificate2.

I tried another thing on the client. After getting the cert, I converted it to a string

```
    DWORD size = 0;
    CryptBinaryToString(cert->pbCertEncoded, cert->cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &size);

    LPWSTR outstring = new TCHAR[size];
    CryptBinaryToString(cert->pbCertEncoded, cert->cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, outstring, &size);
```

If I try to send outstring in the header, it complains:

```
WinHttpAddRequestHeaders: 87: The parameter is incorrect.
```

But when I take the contents of outstring and try to parse it on the server, it decodes back to the right certificate. This tells me that I'm not doing something right when passing cert->pbCertEncoded in the header. Maybe I need to re-encode it or transform it somehow so the server can correctly parse it? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

My client is in c++ and server in .NET. I'm using cpprestsdk to send the certificate in the http request.

Answer (score 0):

The `pbCertEncoded` is the **ASN.1 encoded** representation of the certificate. Look for instance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certcreatecertificatecontext).

So you must encode the bytes to base64 for instance like this:

```cpp
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Crypt32.lib")

int ToBase64Crypto(const BYTE* pSrc, int nLenSrc, char* pDst, int nLenDst )
{
   DWORD nLenOut = nLenDst;
   BOOL fRet = CryptBinaryToString(
    (const BYTE*)pSrc, 
    nLenSrc,
    CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF,
    pDst, &nLenOut
   );
   if (!fRet) {
     nLenOut=0;  // failed
   }
   return (nLenOut);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm already encoding it to base64, if you look at the last code block. Your example is calling the same function CryptBinaryToString. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: As it is only public parts of the certificate, could you post the bytes/string you receive as header on the server side?